# Should I Add String Conditional Method to Helper or Model or ...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to do this?

I have this in a view `<%= badges(challenge) %>` or `<%= challenge.badges %>` depending on if I put `badges` in a helper or the model.

I was told to put it in a helper. I put it in so like this:

```
module ChallengesHelper
  def badges(challenge)
    if challenge.name == "Read 20 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("read.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Exercise 20 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("exercise.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Meditate 10 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("meditate.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Stretch 5 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Write 500 Words"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("write.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Walk 5,000 Steps"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("walk.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Eat Fruit & Veg"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("fruit-and-vegetable.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Plan Day"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("plan.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "After Waking, Guzzle Water"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("water.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Track Food Consumption"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("track-food.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Random Act of Kindness"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("random-kindness.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Write 3 Gratitudes"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("gratitude.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Juice Fast"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("juice.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Not Smoke"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("not-smoke.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Not Drink Alcohol"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("not-drink.png", class: "gold-star")
    # GOAL CHALLENGES
    elsif challenge.name == "Live Abroad"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Long Road Trip"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Tour Capital Building"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Karaoke"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "See New York Skyline"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Run 5K"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Write Memoir"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Lose 10 Pounds"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Join Club"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Skydive"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Start a Blog"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Donate $100 to Charity"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Create Independent Income Stream"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Paint a Picture"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif challenge.name == "Give a Public Speech"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    else
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("gold-star-maze.png", class: "gold-star")
    end
  end
end
```

I'm only concerned because it seems more "wordy" in the helper than the model.

```
  def badges
    if name == "Read 20 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("read.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Exercise 20 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("exercise.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Meditate 10 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("meditate.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Stretch 5 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Write 500 Words"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("write.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Walk 5,000 Steps"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("walk.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Eat Fruit & Veg"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("fruit-and-vegetable.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Plan Day"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("plan.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "After Waking, Guzzle Water"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("water.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Track Food Consumption"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("track-food.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Random Act of Kindness"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("random-kindness.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Write 3 Gratitudes"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("gratitude.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Juice Fast"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("juice.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Not Smoke"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("not-smoke.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Not Drink Alcohol"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("not-drink.png", class: "gold-star")
    # GOAL CHALLENGES
    elsif name == "Live Abroad"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Long Road Trip"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Tour Capital Building"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Karaoke"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "See New York Skyline"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Run 5K"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Write Memoir"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Lose 10 Pounds"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Join Club"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Skydive"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Start a Blog"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Donate $100 to Charity"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Create Independent Income Stream"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Paint a Picture"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Give a Public Speech"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    else
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("gold-star-maze.png", class: "gold-star")
    end
  end
```

Why is one spot better than the other? And what is the best practice for something like this where their are a lot of string conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *best* way would be just to remove this terrible method and store the mapping directly in the model (since it seems pretty static). Something like this:

```
Challenge.create(name: 'Read 20 Min', badge: 'read.png')
```

And helper method becomes much simpler

```
def badge_tag(challenge)
  ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag(challenge.badge, class: "gold-star")
end
```

That's it.

You *could* put this method in the model, but you shouldn't, as it is pure presentation logic, not related to model. Me, I'd use a [presenter](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/) here instead of a helper.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is much better to have something like this in Helper. Less code in model, where you should have only logic needed for model itself. It is logic for view not for model itself, so thats why helpers are there.

And second, better use `case when` than `if elsif.`
You can try to use draper gem. [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps you could take to make this more structured.

1. First of all as others have stated the code is generating view code and doesn't belong in the model, so having it in helper makes more sense.
2. DRY.

Instead of

```
if name == "Read 20 Min"
              ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("read.png", class: "gold-star")
    .
    .
    .
```

should just set the attribute that is to be modified and have the call in a single line ...

```
if name == "Read 20 Min"
      image = "read.png"
else
.
.
end

ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag(image, class: "gold-star")
```

This will be more maintainable, for example you may decide to change the class and only need to modify the one line.

3. Consider adding image name to the challenge model too, then no need to test at all for the description.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to keep this code in your helper, would be to declare a constant with a hash, and use it to avoid `switch` or `if`s:

```
module ChallengesHelper
  CHALLENGE_IMAGES = {
    'Read 20 Min' => 'read.png',
    'Exercise 20 Min' => 'exercise.png',
    'Meditate 10 Min' => 'meditate.png',
    'Stretch 5 Min' => 'stretch.png',
    'Write 500 Words' => 'write.png',
    'Walk 5,000 Steps' => 'walk.png',
    'Eat Fruit & Veg' =>  'fruit-and-vegetable.png',
    'Plan Day' => 'plan.png',
    'After Waking, Guzzle Water' => 'water.png',
    'Track Food Consumption' => 'track-food.png',
    'Random Act of Kindness' => 'random-kindness.png',
    'Write 3 Gratitudes' => 'gratitude.png',
    'Juice Fast' => 'juice.png',
    'Not Smoke' => 'not-smoke.png',
    'Not Drink Alcohol' =>  'not-drink.png',
    'Live Abroad' => 'stretch.png',
    'Long Road Trip' => 'stretch.png',
    'Tour Capital Building' => 'stretch.png',
    'Karaoke' => 'stretch.png',
    'See New York Skyline' => 'stretch.png',
    'Run 5K' => 'stretch.png',
    'Write Memoir' => 'stretch.png',
    'Lose 10 Pounds' => 'stretch.png',
    'Join Club' => 'stretch.png',
    'Skydive' => 'stretch.png',
    'Start a Blog' => 'stretch.png',
    'Donate $100 to Charity' => 'stretch.png',
    'Create Independent Income Stream' => 'stretch.png',
    'Paint a Picture' => 'stretch.png',
    'Give a Public Speech' => 'stretch.png'
  }.freeze

  def badges(challenge)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag(CHALLENGE_IMAGES[challenge] || 'gold-star-maze.png', class: "gold-star")
  end
end
```